# Float rounding problems

Tags: floating-point, cuda, rounding

I finished my thesis in CUDA but I am having a final problem, that has to do with rounding float numbers.

I have an integer variable named bin that is the codification of x+y*X_dim. Given the bin I want to find the x and y coordenates that originated it so I can do a symmetry calculation. This is my original program:

```
float yaux,xaux;
    yaux=(float)floorf((float)bin/((float)DETECTOR_X_DIM));


    if(abs(yaux-floorf(yaux)) < 0.0001)
    yaux=floorf(yaux);
    else
    yaux=ceilf(yaux);


    xaux=(float)((float)(((float)bin/((float)DETECTOR_X_DIM))-(float)yaux)*((float)DETECTOR_X_DIM));

    return (int)xaux;

    if(abs(xaux-floorf(xaux)) < 0.0001)
    xaux=floorf(xaux);
    else
    xaux=ceilf(xaux);
    return (int)xaux;


    xaux = (float)DETECTOR_X_DIM - xaux -(float)1;

    return (int)xaux+(int)yaux*DETECTOR_X_DIM;
```

The problem is that it works for some bins of the detector but it doesnt work for others(it returns xaux added by 1). Is there some better way to this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the code you posted supposed to represent? Presumably not the *actual* code you are using, because as read, it makes absolutely no sense at all. More than half of the code is completely redundant.

Comment: It looks like you're missing some braces ? Either that or most of the code is unreachable...

Comment: Sorry, I made some changes and i forgot to comment the first two returns. I guess I kind of made it using the function roundf and puting xaux = roundf(xaux) instead of the comparison with floor(xaux)

Comment: Please edit the question to fix the code and provide some examples of what works and what does not. It is impossible to provide a useful answer to this question in its current state.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you meant that `bin = x+y*X_dim` where x,y are integer indices you wish to recover given a floating point number `bin` (not necessary an integer) and a known integer constant `X_dim`. I'm basing this on your other questions ([CUDA kernel's vectors' length based on threadIdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5663716/cuda-kernels-vectors-length-based-on-threadidx) and [CUDA 3D matrix index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534732/cuda-3d-matrix-index)) where your code was more readable. In that case you want a simplified equivalent of [Matlab's sub2idx function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html):

```
void Sub2Idx(int& x, int& y, float bin, int X_dim) {
y = (int)(bin / X_dim);
x = (int)(bin) - y*X_dim;
}
```

However, I've assumed you want to round down `bin` along the x-axis. Bilinear interpolation might be more appropriate, but that's far too many assumptions for such an unclear question.

Comment: Sorry for the mess of the question. Basically I have a bin and I want to find its symmetric (bininverse) around the xaxis. So i have to find the x and y integers that originated the normal bin. After that I find x_symmetric and find the symmetric bin like x_symmetric + y*X_dim. The problem was that the roundings that were being made didnt work for all the detector bins. I have just confirmed that I solved the problem, using xaux=roundf(xaux) instead of the comparison shown in the code. Thanks anyway and sorry for the bad-posted question

Comment: You might want to use `rintf()` instead of `roundf()`, it's faster.  It's slightly different in that it rounds to nearest with ties going to even, rather than rounding away from zero for ties.  If that part of the code is in an inner loop it might make a difference in performance.